# Get maximum int key from a map of ints

Tags: go

This code snippet gets the maximum int out of a map's keys

```
func max(numbers map[int]bool) int {
    var maxNumber int
    for n := range numbers {
        maxNumber = n
        break
    }
    for n := range numbers {
        if n > maxNumber {
            maxNumber = n
        }
    }
    return maxNumber
}
```

Comment: why is the first range necessary?

Comment: Because the function doesn't know anything about the contents of the map, to calculate a max (or a min) you need a reference value to start comparing with. 

The map data structure doesn't have a notion of "get first item", thus the first range is one way to get the first key in the map. 

Other comments provide different ways of getting a first element e.g (a different way of using range, or using min int).but in any of them you have to start the comparison against a first element, and also deal with the case where the map is empty (which my function doesn't do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in Abdallah Hodieb's question is good (LGTM).

I prefer the simpler, more readable form of the first `for range` loop.

```
for maxNumber = range numbers {
    break
}
```

The code does not depend on the iteration order over maps. The iteration order over maps is not specified and is not guaranteed to be the same from one iteration to the next.

A zero value map (`nil`) or an empty map reasonably returns the zero value int (`0`). In all other cases, for both 32- and 64-bit `int`s, the result is obviously correct.

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

const (
    maxInt = int(^uint(0) >> 1)
    minInt = -maxInt - 1
)

func max(numbers map[int]bool) int {
    var maxNumber int
    for maxNumber = range numbers {
        break
    }
    for n := range numbers {
        if n > maxNumber {
            maxNumber = n
        }
    }
    return maxNumber
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("maxInt:", maxInt)
    fmt.Println("minInt:", minInt)
    var m map[int]bool
    fmt.Println("max:", max(m), m)
    m = make(map[int]bool)
    fmt.Println("max:", max(m), m)
    m = map[int]bool{maxInt: true}
    fmt.Println("max:", max(m), m)
    m = map[int]bool{1: true}
    fmt.Println("max:", max(m), m)
    m = map[int]bool{0: true}
    fmt.Println("max:", max(m), m)
    m = map[int]bool{-1: true}
    fmt.Println("max:", max(m), m)
    m = map[int]bool{minInt: true}
    fmt.Println("max:", max(m), m)
    m = map[int]bool{maxInt: true, minInt: true}
    fmt.Println("max:", max(m), m)
    m = map[int]bool{0: true, minInt: true}
    fmt.Println("max:", max(m), m)
}
```

Output (64-bit `int`):

```
maxInt: 9223372036854775807
minInt: -9223372036854775808
max: 0 map[]
max: 0 map[]
max: 9223372036854775807 map[9223372036854775807:true]
max: 1 map[1:true]
max: 0 map[0:true]
max: -1 map[-1:true]
max: -9223372036854775808 map[-9223372036854775808:true]
max: 9223372036854775807 map[9223372036854775807:true -9223372036854775808:true]
max: 0 map[0:true -9223372036854775808:true]
```

Output (32-bit `int`):

```
maxInt: 2147483647
minInt: -2147483648
max: 0 map[]
max: 0 map[]
max: 2147483647 map[2147483647:true]
max: 1 map[1:true]
max: 0 map[0:true]
max: -1 map[-1:true]
max: -2147483648 map[-2147483648:true]
max: 2147483647 map[-2147483648:true 2147483647:true]
max: 0 map[0:true -2147483648:true]
```

Comment: I didn't know you use maxNumber in the initial loop (i like it :) )

    for maxNumber = range numbers {
        break
    }

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the first range by initialising `maxNumber` with `math.MinInt(32|64)` depending on the architecture. E.g. on 32-bit systems:

```
func max(numbers map[int]bool) (maxNumber int) {
    maxNumber = math.MinInt32
    for n := range numbers {
        if n > maxNumber {
            maxNumber = n
        }
    }
    return maxNumber
}
```

You can make it work with either system using build tags.

Answer (score 1):

The code in Ainar-G's answer is flawed.

```
func max(numbers map[int]bool) (maxNumber int) {
    maxNumber = math.MinInt32
    for n := range numbers {
        if n > maxNumber {
            maxNumber = n
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't compile: missing return at end of function.

Using build tags to distinguish between 32- and 64-bit `int`s is unnecessary and too complicated. Use local constants, for example,

```
const (
    maxInt = int(^uint(0) >> 1)
    minInt = -maxInt - 1
)
```

A zero value map (`nil`) or an empty map returns the minimum `int` value.  Return the zero value int (`0`).

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

const (
    maxInt = int(^uint(0) >> 1)
    minInt = -maxInt - 1
)

func max(numbers map[int]bool) int {
    var maxNumber int
    if len(numbers) == 0 {
        return maxNumber
    }
    maxNumber = minInt
    for n := range numbers {
        if n > maxNumber {
            maxNumber = n
        }
    }
    return maxNumber
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("maxInt:", maxInt)
    fmt.Println("minInt:", minInt)
    var m map[int]bool
    fmt.Println("max:", max(m), m)
    m = make(map[int]bool)
    fmt.Println("max:", max(m), m)
    m = map[int]bool{maxInt: true}
    fmt.Println("max:", max(m), m)
    m = map[int]bool{1: true}
    fmt.Println("max:", max(m), m)
    m = map[int]bool{0: true}
    fmt.Println("max:", max(m), m)
    m = map[int]bool{-1: true}
    fmt.Println("max:", max(m), m)
    m = map[int]bool{minInt: true}
    fmt.Println("max:", max(m), m)
    m = map[int]bool{maxInt: true, minInt: true}
    fmt.Println("max:", max(m), m)
    m = map[int]bool{0: true, minInt: true}
    fmt.Println("max:", max(m), m)
}
```

Output (64-bit):

```
maxInt: 9223372036854775807
minInt: -9223372036854775808
max: 0 map[]
max: 0 map[]
max: 9223372036854775807 map[9223372036854775807:true]
max: 1 map[1:true]
max: 0 map[0:true]
max: -1 map[-1:true]
max: -9223372036854775808 map[-9223372036854775808:true]
max: 9223372036854775807 map[9223372036854775807:true -9223372036854775808:true]
max: 0 map[0:true -9223372036854775808:true]
```

Output (32-bit):

```
maxInt: 2147483647
minInt: -2147483648
max: 0 map[]
max: 0 map[]
max: 2147483647 map[2147483647:true]
max: 1 map[1:true]
max: 0 map[0:true]
max: -1 map[-1:true]
max: -2147483648 map[-2147483648:true]
max: 2147483647 map[-2147483648:true 2147483647:true]
max: 0 map[-2147483648:true 0:true]
```